# Intellij IDEA, run Javascript code right in the editor

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, firebug

After having written large amounts of code in Intellij Idea Ultimate edition, I often want to test a method, or big pieces.

I often resort to having to paste the code in firebug in firefox, a small annoying cramping space, with no editor features. If the code needs adjusting I need to do it there, test again, copy and insert into Intellij Idea.

Is it possible to run firebug like console code, right in Intellij ? Similar to in Java debug mode with the Inspect tool ? It would have been really useful, even more useful just to highlight some code and press run.

Browser support is not important, any browser will do.

Is this possible already? Is there an Intellij plugin for this? Why not? :(

Thanks!

Comment: Which intelliJ product are you referring to? Idea community or ultimate, webstorm?

Comment: IDEA ultimate, it's like webstorm plus more right ?

Comment: Is it possible in any version?

Answer (score 3):

If the browser is not important, you could use the [node.js](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html) plugin as a javascript repl / debugger. Keep in mind that it will not provide an HTML DOM so if your code makes jQuery calls, it will not run out of the box. Otherwise, if it's just plain javascript, it will run just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled over this. A bit late but anyway:
Debugging Javascript, editing values, etc. works fine using intelliJ with its Chrome Plugin.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-javascript-debugger.html or
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/intellij-idea-debugging-javascript-in-google-chrome/ 
You can set breakpoints to stop where you want and can from there evaluate expressions and all the other stuff you would like to do.
Hope this is what you wanted to know.